# Eval and Bind in EditTemplate Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms

i have a bool value in my data base.
i have true/false and i want to show yes/no to the user.
so i used :

```
Text='<%#Eval("PreOpening").ToString().Equals("False") ?"N":"O" %>'>
```

the problem is : this is an EditItemTemplate so i have to use the Bind to write in the data base.

i tryed

```
Text='<%#Bind("PreOpening").ToString().Equals("False") ?"N":"O" %>'>
```

but this is not working for me .
any one can help plz ?

Comment: try this Text='<%#Eval("PreOpening").ToString().Equals("False",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?"N":"O" %>'>

Comment: juste tryed , the problem is not in the comparison , i have the right value printed , but with Eval i cant insert the value in the base ...

Comment: @MaroineAbdellah if that is the case then use another label set it to visible false and bind the PreOpening to it at the time of edititemtemplate use that value to the enter into the database